# Unexpected $\sqrt{3}$

Tags: random-matrices

A somewhat lengthy calculation, involving integrals, reveals that the probability an $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix, drawn from the Gaussian unitary ensemble, is positive definite, decays as $\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^{-n^2}$ for large $n$. I can’t say what decay constant I had expected, given the context, but it certainly wasn’t $\sqrt{3}$ ! Is there a deeper or more direct explanation for the appearance of this number?

Comment: The Hermitian property means there are only about $n^2/2$ independent entries, so it would make more sense to write it as $3^{-n^2/2}$ and the constant doesn't look strange any more. One can still ask for a heuristic explanation, of course.

Comment: But $n^2$ independent real numbers ... Still, why should there even be a 3?

Comment: I also wasn't exactly expecting Euler's constant $\gamma$ to be so close to $\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$ either, but hey, that's life: it always takes you by surprise! :-)

Comment: Related :  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118481/the-probability-for-a-symmetric-matrix-to-be-positive-definite/

Answer (score 26):

this is a limit of a more general result by Majumdar and company, [How many eigenvalues of a Gaussian random matrix are positive?](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.1107) (2010), see also their earlier papers from [2006](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0609651) and [2008](http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1730).

The coefficient $\sqrt{3}$, or $\frac{1}{2}\log 3$ in the exponent, appears from a saddle point approximation, see Eq. 59 of the 2008 paper, without any particular numerological significance.

Concerning a possible heuristic argument for the number $\sqrt{3}$, here is one [published argument](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0512050) that gives $\sqrt{e}$, close but not quite correct.

Comment: In fact, this constant comes from minimizing the rate function of BenArous and Guionnet  http://www.math.nyu.edu/~benarous/Publications/benarous_30.pdf over measures which are supported over the positive part of the real axis. This is essentially what Majumdar and als do.